# Avoiding wildcard expansion in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

Here is my code where I try to print each character of a string:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 seq="2 + 3 * 4"
 for i in $seq ; do
    echo "printing $i"
 done
```

But when I reach the "*" character of the string $seq the program prints all the files in the folder where the file is held. Here is the sample output of above code:

```
printing 2
printing +
printing 3
printing file
printing fileHandle.pl
printing indentation.sh
printing line_no.sh
```

How to get the * character to be printed by the above loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable globbing for that specifc session:

```
shopt -s -o noglob

seq="2 + 3 * 4"
for i in $seq ; do
    echo "printing $i"
done

shopt -u -o noglob  ## Optionally enable it back
```

Ouput:

```
printing 2
printing +
printing 3
printing *
printing 4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `read -a`:

```
#!/bin/bash

seq="2 + 3 * 4"

read -ra arr <<< "$seq"
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: +1 was going to post exactly same. Much better than brute force method of disabling globing.

Comment: I was about to add the idea :) +1

Answer (score 1):

This is stupid but works too:

```
seq="2 + 3 * 4"

while read -rd ' ' token; do
    echo "printing $token"
done <<< "$seq "
```